# Virtualhosts pointing to the first virtualhost directory

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, virtual-hosts

I have a problem in my httpd.conf.

All my VirtualHosts I created from the WebMin interface are pointing to the same directory despite I give a specific directory for each VH. The directory which actually pointing is from the first VH(when I change the position of the VH, it's always the first VH directory).

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how Webmin handles virtual hosts, but Apache needs a NameVirtualHost directive

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

You can add it to your httpd.conf as well. Sometimes it is in ports.conf or in the default virtual host (000-default)